# Python Zeep is throwing unkown fault for soap request

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, soapui, zeep

I am new to using the framework zeep. I am trying to send a SOAP request .  But I get the  below incorrect data. I need to get the response in xml or csv format.

<Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope at 0x7fabdc9ea888>

With the wsdl, I am able to fetch the correct output using SoapUI tool.

```
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport
from requests.auth import AuthBase, HTTPBasicAuth
import datetime

wsdl = 'http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:ZZZZ/TL/IM?wsdl'

session = Session()
session.auth = SymantecAuth('user','password', "http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX")
session.verify = False
transport = Transport(session=session)

client = Client(wsdl=wsdl, transport=transport)

request_data = {"platforms": "test", "platid": {"ID": "QI4552"}}

results=client.create_message(client.service, 'RetrieveID', request_data)
print(results)
```

Comment: Show us the error you receive

Comment: I do not get any error . I just get the below .
<Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope at 0x7fabdc9ea888>

Comment: its printing the `results` object. Try `print(results.content)`

Comment: I tried. It gives below error.
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'contents'

Comment: Did you type `print(results.content)` or `print(results.contents)` ?

Comment: I have tried both. Both fails. 
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'content'

Comment: is it possible to share output of this command: `python -m zeep  'http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:ZZZZ/TL/IM?wsdl'` ? please use real url.

Comment: Actually . It is not possible to share here

Comment: Can you share what does `create_message` method returns? It's definition if possible?

Comment: It is a zeep method . PFB. When you want zeep to build and return the XML instead of sending it to the server you can use the Client.create_message() call.

Comment: aha yeah. sorry.

Comment: Use PDB to track down what object the "results" actually is. You can use things like "dir(results)" to see what attributes and methods it has. This should give you an idea how the object is created and what it's options are.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating the message, `print(results)` is just showing the message object created.

Instead this should work to print the message on screen:

```
from lxml import etree

# Your code follows here

results=client.create_message(client.service, 'RetrieveID', request_data)
# this will print the message to be sent to Soap service.
print(etree.tostring(results, pretty_print=True))
```

If you want to see the response of the `RetrieveID` operation. then do this instead (Provided this method is bound on 1st available binding):

```
response = client.service.RetrieveID(**request_data)
print(response)
```

Let us know if it doesn't work.

Comment: The above is not giving the output. IT is just printing the input as an xml

Comment: this is what you asked for to print the result in xml or csv. no?

Comment: do you want to get the response of `RetrieveID` method call?

Comment: Yes. I need the response in xml or csv formst

Comment: If it worked, please mark the answer as accepted otherwise let us know the issue.

Comment: It did not work. It throws the below error.
TypeError: {http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7}RetrieveIncidentRequest() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'. Signature: `model: {http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7}IncidentModelType, attachmentInfo: xsd:boolean, attachmentData: xsd:boolean, ignoreEmptyElements: xsd:boolean, updatecounter: xsd:boolean, handle: xsd:string, count: xsd:long, start: xsd:long`

I am using the below code now .
request_data = {"keys": "test", "instance": {"IncidentID": "IM14150"}}
response = = client.service.RetrieveIncident(**request_data)
print(response)

Comment: If you can show us the definition of `RetrieveID` method from this command: `python -m zeep <wsdl_url>` ? Then we can surely help you get what you wanted.